# Port forwarding, remote host, no-ip (static IP access) problems

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, static-ip

Im trying to run my custom game server on my local machine. I used no-ip.com to create a static internet location for my game to connect to. I downloaded their DUC program that should  access my data on that location and deliver it to my computer.

To check if everything works as it should be I am using this site to confirm that my ports are accessible http://canyouseeme.org/ (I also tried some similar sites..).

I forwarded all ports on my router to my computer ( have also tried port triggering and some other options), I also added new rule to my Win7 firewall (firewall is turned down but just in case).

I keep getting "Connection refused" from canyouseeme.org... They say it means that there are firewall issues.

I did menage to get the whole thing to run with "SPI port forwarding" program (http://download.cnet.com/SPI-Port-Forward/3000-2651_4-10764348.html?tag=downloadRatingModule;summaryRatings)
but i want to know what I am doing wrong and how to do this manually.

And ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely that program uses [UPnP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) to request a port forwarding from your home router. This is a pretty standard protocol for port forwarding and most home routers support it.

In order to make it permanent or configure it manually, you need to log in to your router to make the changes. How you do this depends on the router model (you didn't mention it).

Comment: Its thompson (cant really tell what specific atm)... I have "UPnP eneble" option, I enabled it, same thing...

Comment: Flip it over and look at its label to find a model number, then you can find instructions at http://portforward.com/ .

Comment: Kinda not in position atm (other room, parents sleeping and stuff :) ), i did try to find it on that site however, but they have only 1 thomson model there... I did check out what my ISP provides and I think its Thomson TWG850-4 or TWG870 (they seem to have same interface)...

Answer (score 0):

Some older residential routers just straight up don't port forward. Don't get me wrong, they have the option to do it, but it's janky and rarely works.

You could however port forward it using something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). I believe it can really help in your case as it allows you to port forward a port/port range and get a sub-domain instead of the IP.